# remove (what's on your mind ) in sharedialog or customize it on facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook sdk 3.5.2 android and would like to remove what's on your mind or customize it to my own text .How do I do that ? I am using the code below and it shows the  what's on your mind bar.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance

```
       FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
    .setLink("setlink").setCaption("setcaption").setDescription("setdescription").setName("setname").setPicture("pic")
build();


uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Comment: You can't. It's set by the Facebook app.

Comment: Can I customize the message?

Comment: No, that's against policy, see section IV.2 of https://developers.facebook.com/policy/